# Visual Studio IDE Error On Launch When Loading Project

Tags: visual-studio, designer

I am loading my project into Visual Studio 2019 IDE. When I go into the forms designer within the IDE
Visual Studio Forms Designer has been gives me the following error:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch.

There is no code associated with it. All referenced DLLs haven't changed.
Has anyone else experienced this or have a work around as the Google searches I have done have given me to help. Is there a way to narrow down the error? I have also checked all the security dlls to make sure they are correct and are referenced locally to help. Maybe something to do with the CAS policy?

I have also tried on my installed versions of 2012, 2015, & 2017.

**UPDATE:** Updated the error above as I had the wrong error added.

Comment: Opening the designer for a Winforms project can automatically execute code, Microsoft is not exactly happy about that when the storage location for the project is not trusted.  Like a file server on a LAN.  Work around with Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General, untick "Warn user when the project location is not trusted".  Or google "caspol trust network share".

Comment: @HansPassant Gave this a try but no luck.